# How to use if else statements in loops within an existing tibble

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm attempting to create a new variable which combines two existing variables.  I've taught myself how to do this with an if else statement with a loop.  However, all of the examples online create variables to use in their if else loops by assigning a few values to a variable name.  I understand why the online examples do this, but it makes it hard for me to figure out how to incorporate the if else loop into an existing tibble.

The new variable should use values from one existing variable (b) if they are not missing and values from another existing variable (a) if the scores for the first variable (b) are missing.  At time 1, participants might have taken test a, test b, or both.  I've filtered out those participants who took neither test.  Now I'm trying to create a new variable (c) which combines the two tests.  If participants took test b (is not missing), the new variable should reflect test b scores.  If participants did not take test b (is missing), the new variable should reflect test a scores.  I can make an example work using the code below, but I can't get a similar format to work with the variables in my actual data.

```
a <- c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
b <- c(10, NA, 30, NA, NA, 40, 50)

c <- vector("double")
for (i in seq_along(b)) {
  if (!is.na(b[i])) {
    c[i] <- (b[i])
  } else {
    c[i] <- (a[i])
  }
}

c
```

Comment: `c <- ifelse(is.na(b), a, b)` looks better. Could you make an example that does not work using ifelse?

Comment: The ifelse() function is so much easier than the if else loop I created.  This solved the problem since I could incorporate it into a mutate function.  I've been teaching myself R, and apparently I hadn't found ifelse() yet.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy to be useful!